# argdo vs bufdo for project-wide search and replace in specific folders

Tags: search, buffers, substitute, argument-list

I have the following structure:

```
myproject
    ----src
       file1.cpp, ..., file10.cpp
    ----include
       incl1.h, ..., incl10.h
    ----data
       data1.txt, ..., data10.txt
```

I would like to restrict my searches and search-and-replaces to only the `/src/` and `/include/` subfolders.

To accomplish this, my current thought process is to populate the arglist directly via .vimrc by means of the following line in .vimrc:

```
:arg ./src/** ./include/** <CR>
```

As of now, this opens up vim with 20 files in the buffer itself. That is, as soon as the project opens within vim, if I issue `:ls` command, then `file1.cpp` through `incl10.h` are shown in the buffer list.

1. Does this mean that at this point in time, `argo` and `bufdo` would accomplish the same thing? *i.e.*, are these two commands the same?

```
:bufdo %s/search/replace/g
:argdo %s/search/replace/g
```

I would imageine that in situations where the output of `:arg` and the output of `:ls` are not the same, `argdo` and `bufdo` would give different results to the above search and replaces.

2. When vim opens with the above .vimrc, before entering vim, I obtain the following :

   "./src/file1.cpp" [dos] 587L, 20677C
   Press Enter or type command to continue

Is there a way to suppress this message?

3. In trying to run `:argdo %s/search/replace/g`, is there a way to make it interactive? That is, can I map this to say `<C-s>r` via .vimrc and then I get prompted for the word that should go into `<search>` placeholder, and the word that should go into `<replace>` placeholder?
4. Is the above workflow even good practice? *i.e.*, populating an argument list via .vimrc for subsequent usage in searches and search-and-replaces?

Comment: 1)yes, 2)probably yes, 3) yes, 4) no. Sorry for not providing proper answers, I think you would have more detailed ones if you have asked them separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Meta

This question is long (4 questions), and we normally prefer to keep questions to
1 question per question. The 4th is also opinion-based enough to be off-topic.

However, the questions are related enough and I have enough to say that I'm
going to (try to) write an answer.

---

Your questions first:

> 1. Does this mean that at this point in time, `argo` and `bufdo` would
>    accomplish the same thing? *i.e.*, are these two commands the same?

```
:bufdo %s/search/replace/g
:argdo %s/search/replace/g
```

Well, if `:args` and `:ls` give the same result, then yes, probably. (You may
want the `e` flag, `:help :s_e`.)

> I would imageine [sic] that in situations where the output of `:arg` and the
> output of `:ls` are not the same, `argdo` and `bufdo` would give different
> results to the above search and replaces.

Correct. Note that `:bufdo` should skip `unlisted-buffer`s, per my reading of
it.

> 2. When vim opens with the above .vimrc, before entering vim, I obtain the
>    following :

```
"./src/file1.cpp" [dos] 587L, 20677C
Press Enter or type command to continue
```

> Is there a way to suppress this message?

You could try `:silent`, but see below.

> 3. In trying to run `:argdo %s/search/replace/g`, is there a way to make it
>    interactive? That is, can I map this to say `<C-s>r` via .vimrc and then I
>    get prompted for the word that should go into `<search>` placeholder, and
>    the word that should go into `<replace>` placeholder?

Of course: something like (in this version you have to press enter after the
prompts, so you have a chance to make corrections/etc.).

```
nnoremap <expr> <C-s>r ':argdo %s/'.escape(input('search '), '/').'/'.escape(input('replace '), '/').'/g'
```

> 4. Is the above workflow even good practice? *i.e.*, populating an argument
>    list via .vimrc for subsequent usage in searches and search-and-replaces?

Well, I think not. I'll talk all about search & replace (S&R) below, but setting
the arglist in your vimrc

- prevents `vim <file>…` from working the normal way;
- makes your vimrc specific to one and only one project; and
- limits your understanding of S&R.

If you want a special arglist, use [session](/questions/tagged/session)s. Even vanilla `:mksession` and `vim -S` are quite good, though I recommend
[obsession](https://github.com/tpope/vim-obsession) for the avid session user.

---

So, let's talk S&R.

> I would like to restrict my searches and search-and-replaces to only the
> `/src/` and `/include/` subfolders.

Great. How do you search? How do you replace?

#### On searching

There are a myriad of options:

- `/` (always only the current file)
- `:grep` (can easily be restricted)
- `:vimgrep` (idem.)

and probably more. The last two populate the quickfix list (there are location
list variants that start with `l`). We'll come back to this.

The last two also take file names, which can be generated from the arglist if
you like (`##`), or *any* other way of getting filenames (`:help {file}`).

#### On replacing

The ubiquitous `:substitute` command is one way, though there are others
(macros, complex `:normal`- or `:`-commands, `:global`, basically anything you
would do interactively, &c.) that can be done from the ex command line.

As for targeting those replacements, you know the `%` range and
`:argdo`/`:bufdo`. But there are also `:windo`, `:tabdo`, and more. Some
favorites include `:cdo` and `:cfdo`, which iterate the quickfix list (see
above). (Location list variants exist.) Combine with `:Cfilter` (`:help cfilter-plugin`) for a very powerful workflow:

1. Search your desired files with one of the `:grep` variants.
2. Refine the quickfix list with `:Cfilter` if necessary.
3. Use `:cdo` (with no range) or `:cfdo` (with a `%` range) to run your
   replacement command.

This has the benefit of no longer needing the `e` flag for `:substitute`.

With smart `grepprg`s, you can limit to different files very easily. For
example, `git grep` has lots of options and takes pathspecs as arguments (see
`git help glossary` and search for `pathspec`; you usually have to quote them
for the shell). Tools like `ripgrep` (`ag`/`ack`/etc.) can usually filter by
file-type.